# create a list of method references with different target object?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, lambda

I am still digesting the lambda conception in Java 8. Now it comes to a need of create a list of method references in my service, which has 2 other services objects. This is what needs to happen

```
Person person = new Person();
this.method1(person);
service2.method2(person);
service3.method3(person);
```

so the list should have

```
0 -> this.method1,
1 -> service2.method2,
2 -> service3.method3,
```

It is very important that no new instances of this.class, service2 or service3 is created. Not sure the best way to achieve that. Can I have some help?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you just want a

```
List<Consumer<Person>> list = Arrays.asList(
    this::method1, service2::method2, service3::method3);
for (Consumer<Person> action : list) {
  action.accept(person);
}
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question when unit testing it, if my service2 and service3 are created by Mockito.mock, do you think    service2.method2 in the list   is gonna invoke the  method2 of   mocked service2?   I keep getting   'wanted but not invoked'

Comment: Yes, there should be nothing special there.

Comment: yeah, I have found the problem. Thank you for assuring.

Comment: hate to bug again. is it possible to log the operation? It seems action does not have the knowledge of what operation it is :(

Comment: Not really, not unless you eg use a map from String instead of a list.